# Can column name be "Group" in PostgreSQL or in any databases

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, syntax, quoted-identifier

I was designing a project which specifies that in a table what column name should be and one of the column name in the specification is "group".

I tried creating it but it always throw a syntax error near the word = `"group"`. I am really curious since the keyword in SQL is "group by" not group, so what is the reason, I cannot rename or create a column with a name `"group".`

Syntax and error I am using and getting:

```
ALTER TABLE test RENAME COLUMN sum TO group;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "group"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE test RENAME COLUMN sum TO group;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`group` *is* a reserved word (and `by` is another reserved word) - it's not `GROUP BY` that is reserved. Because it is a reserved word, it cannot be used directly as an identifier.

To use a reserved word or a name with "illegal" characters (such as a space) for an identifier, you need to quote the identifier.

```
ALTER TABLE test RENAME COLUMN sum TO "group";
```

Note that when using quoted identifiers, you need to **always** quote it. And it becomes case sensitive. `"group"` is a different column name than `"GROUP"`.

For more details please [see the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

In general it is a very bad idea to use names that require quoting. It will save you a *lot* of trouble if you can come up with a different name that does not require quoting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use a reserved keyword as a column name make sure you use the inverted qoute. Sometimes double qoutes wont work in MYSQL.

keep group in the query within `

` is present on the left top of the keyboard. same key as tilde (~)